# Как корректно отправить и получить кроссдоменный запрос axios (мост vue-axios) в VueJS на API яндекс расписания с локального хоста порт 8000 (CORS)

Tags: vue.js, api, get, axios, cors

Таким образом посылаю запрос на [API яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/), но проблема с `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` заголовком.
Почитал инфу, понял в чём соль, но как настроить кроссдоменность используя axios (мост из vue-axios) в VueJS. Сборка вебпак. Сервак нод на локальном хосте на порту 8000. Как настроить, как правильно отправить запрос и принять ответ.

```
mounted(){
    this.$http
    .get('https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/search/?apikey="ключик к api яндекса"&format=json&from=c146&to=c213&lang=ru_RU&page=1&date=2018-11-13')
      .then(response => (this.info = response));
      console.log(this.info)
  }
}
```

В main.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

Comment: Переформируйте заголовок вопроса на более осмысленный

Comment: Вы не поняли то, что я имею ввиду? При попытке отправки запроса браузер выдаёт следующее: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:// api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/search/?apikey="тут ключ для API"&format=json&from=c146&to=c213&lang=ru_RU&page=1&date=2018-11-13' from origin 'http:// localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Вот я и спрашиваю, как корректно отправить и получить кроссдоменный запрос, как и где задать требуемый заголовок?

Comment: Насколько я понял из документации, ключ к API регистрируется для доменного имени, а так же при запросе необходимо указание заголовка `Referer`. Ошибку вы получаете по тому что пытаетесь сделать запрос с неразрешенного хоста, или у вас не было `OPTION` запроса. Попробуйте добавить заголовок `Referer` с хостом из личного кабинета.

Answer (score -1):

в axios надо поставить withCredentials: true